Ckeditor 4 - toggling source mode only enables mathjax
I am using reactJS and CKEditor 4 ->
I want to be able to dispay mathjax formulas coming from an API.
I am fetching data that has mathjax but it's not displaying formula properly until and unless i Switch or toggle the mode from rich text to source and then back.
This is causing another issue where the instance of ckeditor is not found by setdata method and the data itslef does not load on teh editor.
Any thoughts on this issue

Have you read the documentation about typesetting new math that you insert into the page?
